# The type or namespace "SPTool" name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?

Tags: visual-studio

```
using System;
using SPTool.Library;
namespace ConsoleApplicationExmFeature
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SPTSite site = new SPTSite("http://itcdev33");

            // Activate site collection scoped feature
           // SPTReturn returnObj = site.ActivateFeature("SPTool.Site.Config", false);

            // Activate site collection scoped feature using Guid
             SPTReturn returnObj = site.ActivateFeature("32529c03-833d-4c5e-a15e-0bcb35bdedad", false);

            // Check the status of Activating the feature
            if (returnObj.State == SPTState.Success)
            {
                // Activating Feature Successful
                Console.WriteLine("Activating Feature Successful");
            }
            else
            {
                // Activating Feature Failed
                Console.WriteLine("Activating Feature Failed");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already added an assembly reference and deployed the assembly in gac, still getting an error while compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this library if all you want is to activate a feature. Just add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint dll  and following is the code sample to activate a web scoped feature:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://itcdev33"))
    {
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        Guid featureGuid = new Guid("32529c03-833d-4c5e-a15e-0bcb35bdedad");
        web.Features.Add(featureGuid);
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }           
}
```

To add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint dll, Right Click on Project Reference, Select Add Reference, Click on Browse and browse to folder C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI in case of SP 2013 and if it is SP 2010 use 14 instead of 15 in folder name and select Microsoft.SharePoint.

[image]

Comment: Now I am getting this error.The type or namespace “Sharepoint” name does not exist in namespace Microsoft (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)? Though I have deployed the assembly and added reference.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry sir, still getting that same error.

Comment: Adding using Microsoft.SharePoint; at top of the file.

Comment: I am using VS2010

Comment: I have already added that.

Comment: That is strange, all you need to do is to add the dll reference and use the using statement and everything should work.